# Copy JAR files to AS400 and execute it

Tags: java, ibm-midrange

How do I copy a JAR-File and some files this JAR need to an AS400 machine and start the JAR there?

Comment: Though you probably don't know it, because you don't know the IBM midrange platform, this amounts to a question about the environment called PASE and the file system called IFS. See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55709487/ibm-i-what-use-is-pase).

Comment: My recommendation on the question I linked to applies here as well: Join [one](https://lists.midrange.com/mailman/listinfo/midrange-l) [or](https://lists.midrange.com/mailman/listinfo/java400-l) [more](https://lists.midrange.com/mailman/listinfo/opensource) of the midrange mailing lists and the [IBM i open source community on Ryver](https://ibmioss.ryver.com/application/signup/members/9tJsXDG7_iSSi1Q). You should be able to get plenty of help at those places.

Answer (score 1):

FTP, network share, sftp, iACS IFS function.

If using FTP, be sure to enable BINARY mode.